# Translate the Maude code into Coq

Tags: coq

I want to translate the Maude code I wrote before to Coq since Coq has more powerful expression than Maude.

I have no idea how to represent the following code:
[image]

As shown above, the **GuardPostfix** has three subsorts: **GuardPostfix1**, **GuardPostfix2** and **GuardPostfix3**.

I use inductive type to denote the **GCcomponent**. However, when defining the type **GComponent**, **GComponent1** has two constructors that use the constructor **GuardPostfix1** and **GuardPostfix2** respectively.

How can I define these types in Coq?

Answer (score 2):

I think the general recipe is to translate all Maude sorts into Coq types, and to represent Maude subsort relationships as the supersort having constructors for all of its subsorts (eg, `subsort A B < C` becomes `Definition C := A + B`). Following that general rule here's how I translated your example. Note that I don't know Maude, so it's possibly I missed something about the example itself. Also, I would strongly consider using a new inductive rather than the generic sum type (`+`) for `GuardPostfix` and `GComponent`, but that's up to you.

```
Module GuardedComponent.

  Parameter BoolExp:Type.
  Parameter Assignment:Type.
  Parameter Program:Type.
  Parameter Index:Type.
  Parameter EndPoint:Type.
  Parameter Null:Type.
  Parameter EventGuard:Type.
  Parameter TimeControl:Type.

  Inductive AssignmentGuard :=
  | mkAssignmentGuard (_:BoolExp) (_:Assignment).

  Inductive GuardPostfix1 :=
  | mkGuardPostfix1 (_:Program) (_:Index).

  Inductive GuardPostfix2 :=
  | mkGuardPostfix2 (_:Program) (_:EndPoint).

  Inductive GuardPostfix3 :=
  | mkGuardPostfix3 (_:Program) (_:Null).

  Definition GuardPostfix : Type :=
    GuardPostfix1 + GuardPostfix2 + GuardPostfix3.

  Inductive GComponent1 :=
  | comp1_post1 (_:GuardPostfix1)
  | comp1_post2 (_:GuardPostfix2).

  Inductive GComponent2 :=
  | mkGComponent2 (_:EventGuard) (_:GuardPostfix3).

  Inductive GComponent3 :=
  | mkGComponent3 (_:TimeControl) (_:GuardPostfix3).

  Definition GComponent : Type :=
    GComponent1 + GComponent2 + GComponent3.

End GuardedComponent.
```

Comment: If I define a function that may return the type of **GComponent1**, **GComponent2** or **GComponent3**, can I use the type **GComponent** to represent the different types?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to explicitly use `inl (inl ...)`, `inl (inr ...)` and `inr ...` in order to convert from the sub-component types to a `GComponent`.